# Strange behavior in Java-JList searching

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jlist

I've been struggling for hours with this method which has a strange behavior.
Scenario: two jlists, menuList and productList filled with data from a mysql db, the first contains the "categories" and the second the products of that category. Both of them are populated with a Vector of objects. The problem is when I perform a search of a products it works fine in all circumstances except immediately after I save a new menu (category). In this case, the index of the menuList is successfully moved to the right category in which the products I was searching is in, but productList remains blank.
This is the code of the method which makes the search.

```
 private void bFindProductActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)     {                                             
    Product product = new Product();
    product.setProductName(searchedProduct.getText());
    bNewProduct.setEnabled(false);
    Vector<Product> productVoices = DBConnection.searchProduct(product);
    if (!productVoices.isEmpty()) {
        modelProductList.clear();
        disableProductButtons();
        menuName.setText("");
        productName.setText("");
        int idMenu = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < productVoices.size(); i++) {
            Product current = (Product) productVoices.get(i);
            modelProductList.addElement(current);
            idMenu = current.getMenuId();
        }
        productList.setModel(modelProductList);
        for (int i = 0; i < modelMenuList.getSize(); i++) {
            Menu current = (Menu) modelMenuList.getElementAt(i);
            if (idMenu == current.getMenuId()) {
                int currentId = modelMenuList.indexOf(current);
                menuList.setSelectedIndex(currentId);
                menuList.requestFocus();
            }
        }
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No product found", "", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        searchedProduct.setText("Search...");
    }

}
```

And this is the code of the methos which saves a new menu (or updates an existing one):

```
private void bSaveMenuActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

        //If there's a selected menu updates
        if (!menuList.isSelectionEmpty()) {
            Menu selectedMenu = (Menu) menuList.getSelectedValue();
            listIndex = menuList.getSelectedIndex();
            selectedMenu.setMenuName(menuName.getText());
            int result = DBConnection.updateMenu(selectedMenu);
            if (result == 1) {
                reloadMenuList(); //this re-fill the menuList
                menuList.setSelectedIndex(listIndex);
                menuList.setEnabled(true);
                bFindProduct.setEnabled(true);
                bNewMenu.setEnabled(true);
                bNewProduct.setEnabled(false);

            }

        } else { //If there isn't a selected menu, creates a new menu
            Menu newMenu = new Menu();
            newMenu.setMenuName(menuName.getText());
            int result = DBConnection.insertMenu(newMenu);
            if (result == 1) {
                reloadMenuList();
                newMenuIsSaved = true; 
                menuList.setEnabled(true);
                bFindProduct.setEnabled(true);

            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: 1. Menu is awt.Menu, if yes then use Swing JMenu, otherwise rename this variable, 2. I've been struggling for hours with this method which has a strange behavior. be sure that we are too, for better help sooner post an SSCCE, short runnable, compilable with hardcoded value for JList in local variable

Comment: Thank you but in the meanwhile I resolved. And the problem was in other part of the code. Too complex to explain.